# How umask() system call is masking the permission

Tags: linux

I am using `umask()` system call to set file permission. I am using the following code :

```
umask(S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH);
printf("Enter file name that you want to create:");
scanf(" %s",file);
fd = open(file,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY);
```

But after executing it file is created with the given below permissions

```
--wS-----T 1 rvi rvi     0 Oct  2 15:20 test.txt
```

What is this `S` bit and `T` bit for ? and why it is modified automatically ?

Comment: `S` means the setuid bit is set without actual execute permission and `T` means the sticky bit is set without write permission for "others".

Comment: Thank you for that.....but how it is automatically modified ?

Comment: No clue. That's why I went for a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: ok...thanx..@JosephR.

Comment: btw, the third line shouldn' it be  `scanf("%s", &file);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call open with O_CREAT, it expects a third argument for the mode of the file. The umask is then masked out from the mode you request. So, for example:

```
umask(S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH /* == 0022 */);
fd = open(file, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0777);
```

would create a file with flags 0777 & (~0022) = 0755, i.e., rwxr-xr-x, whereas:

```
umask(S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH);
fd = open(file, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0666);
```

would create a file with flags 0666 & (~0022) = 0644, i.e., rw-r--r--. In your case, because you didn't supply a mode argument, the open function takes random data off the stack, so the only thing you know is that the bits masked off with umask will be off. Try supplying your desired mode to the open call; 0777 is a good choice for executable files and 0666 is a good one for non-executables.

Comment: It works....thanx..:)

Comment: a small note, files can be given max `0666` whereas folders `0777`, the difference arises from `execute` flag.